# a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char" C OOP

Tags: c++, oop

I am creating a class to calculate a grade for a user in C++ and I am coming across a simple yet annoying problem. I know what the errors means but I don't understand how to fix it and changing to a string actually fixes the issue but this is not what I want to do.

here is the error: const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char

Code

```
    #include <string>
using namespace std;

class Gradecalc
{
public:
    Gradecalc()
    {
        mark = 0;
    }
    int getmark()
    {
        return mark;
    }
    void setmark(int inmark)
    {
        mark = inmark;

    }
    void calcgrade()
    {
        if (mark >=70)
        {
            grade = "A";      //**ERROR IS HERE**
        }

    }
    char getgrade()
    {
        return grade;
    }

private:
    int mark;
    char grade; //VARIABLE IS DECLARED HERE
};
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

C++ has two types of constants consisting of characters - string literals and character literals.

- String literals are enclosed in double quotes, and have type of `const char *`
- Character literals are enclosed in single quotes, and have type `char`.

String literals allow multiple characters; character literals allow only one character. The two types of literals are not compatible: you need to supply a variable or a constant of a compatible type for the left side of the assignment. Since you declared `grade` as a `char`, you need to change the code to use a character literal, like this:

```
grade ='A';
```

Answer (score 2):

C and C++ use double quotes to indicate "string literal", which is *very* different from a "character literal".

`char` (which is signed) is a type capable of storing a character representation in the compiler's default character set. On a modern, Western PC, that means ASCII, which is a character set that requires 7-bits, plus one for sign. So, `char` is generally an 8-bit value or byte.

A character literal is formed using single quotes, so `'A'` evaluates to ASCII code 65. (`'A' == 65`).

On the other hand, `"A"` causes the compiler to write char(65) + char(0) into a part of the output program and then evaluates the expression `"A"` to the address of that sequence; thus it evaluates to a pointer to a char sequence, but they're in the program data itself so they are not modifiable, hence `const char*`.

You want

```
grade = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
grade = "A";
```

by

```
grade = 'A';
```

You can only assign char to char, you cannot assign string to single char, and that is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`Grade` is a `char` variable, `"A"` is a `const char*` type.

You cannot assign `const char*` into `char` varible.

double quote means `const char*`, and single qoute means char.

to fix that, replace:

> grade="A"

with

> grade='A'.