# C++: How do I modify a global char string?

Tags: c++, c

In the following code snippet, I am not able to understand why the error is coming on LineA , but no error in Line B ?

```
//Global 
char strA[80] = "A string to be used for demonstration purposes";

int t=60;  

int main(void)
    {    

        strA[80] = "I am trying to modify the source";  //Line A, gives error 

        t=60;   //Line B, no errors 

   }
```

The error is:

> 2 IntelliSense: a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to
>   an entity of type
>   "char"    c:\users\hu\cplustutorial.cpp   69  12  CPLUStutorial

I am not having the char string  as `const`, so why this error?

Compiling with MS VS 2010.

Comment: If you think this has anything with the string being global, make it local first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `char strA[80] = "A string to be used for demonstration purposes";` initializes your array.

This `strA[80]` means a single character within that array. How can you store multiple characters in a single char. Use `strcpy` to copy the new string.

Comment: @user3891236 - That is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign the 80th element of `strA` (which incidentally doesn't exist) with a `const char*`, not the `char[]` itself. Also, you tagged the question as C++, so why use `char[]` instead of `std::string`?

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the type of a string literal is **`const`** `char[]`,  not plain `char[]`, so what you are trying to do is illegal by the C++ standard, hence the error you are seeing.

In order to modify the string you will first need to copy it, either using the C library function `strcpy` or (better) with a `std::string`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to understand a string of character(string literal) has a type of `const char *` and you are trying to store it inside a single char(`char[80]`). Thats why its giving you error.Check this out http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/20294015/.

Comment: Note that the type of a string literal is `const char[N]`, not `const char*`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Just used to using its array-to-pointer version.